# run function after element generated jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have function written in one js file with deferred and promise. After that I am calling that function in another HTML file where I create menu this page will work as web part. So I want to run the function after that menu generate, how can I do that.

```
Ph.DAL = function() {
  this.getRequest = function(listName, select, filter, orderby, top, _async) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred()
    var request = baseRequest
    request.type = 'GET'
    request.async = _async
    request.url =
      siteAbsoluteUrl +
      "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" +
      listName +
      "')/items?" +
      (this.isNullOrEmpty(select) ? '' : '$select=' + select) +
      '&' +
      (this.isNullOrEmpty(filter) ? '' : '$filter=' + filter) +
      '&' +
      (this.isNullOrEmpty(orderby) ? '' : '$orderby=' + orderby) +
      '&' +
      (this.isNullOrEmpty(top) ? '' : '$top=' + top)
    request.headers = { ACCEPT: 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
    dfd = $.ajax(request)
    return dfd.promise()
  }
```

Which I am calling from another html page to generate dynamic menu

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var utility = new Ph.DAL()
    var menuHTML = ''
    utility
      .getRequest(
        'Navigation',
        'Id,Title,Icon,URL,Target,ParentId,OrderBy',
        "Active eq 'Yes'",
        '',
        '',
        true
      )
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data && data.d && data.d.results && data.d.results.length > 0) {
          createMenu(data.d.results, null)
        }
        $('#respMenu').html(menuHTML)
        $('#respMenu').aceResponsiveMenu({
          resizeWidth: '768', // Set the same in Media query
          animationSpeed: 'fast', //slow, medium, fast
          accoridonExpAll: false, //Expands all the accordion menu on click
        })
      })
    function createMenu(jSON, parentId) {
      var _menu
      _menu = Enumerable.from(jSON)
        .where(function(value) {
          return value.ParentId == parentId
        })
        .orderBy(function(value) {
          return value.OrderBy
        })
        .toArray()
      if (_menu.length > 0) {
        _menu.map(function(item, i) {
          menuHTML +=
            '<li class="' +
            (item.URL.toLowerCase() == utility.pageName.toLowerCase() ? 'active' : '') +
            '"><a href="' +
            item.URL +
            '">'
          menuHTML +=
            '<i class="' +
            item.Icon +
            '"></i><span class="title">' +
            item.Title +
            '</span></a>'
          var subMenu = Enumerable.from(jSON)
            .where(function(value) {
              return value.ParentId == item.Id
            })
            .orderBy(function(value) {
              return value.OrderBy
            })
            .toArray()
          if (subMenu.length > 0) {
            createSubMenu(jSON, subMenu)
          }
          menuHTML += '</li>'
        })
      }
    }
    function createSubMenu(mainData, data) {
      menuHTML += '<ul>'
      data.map(function(item, i) {
        menuHTML += '<li><a href="' + item.URL + '">' + item.Title + '</a>'
        var subMenu = Enumerable.from(mainData)
          .where(function(value) {
            return value.ParentId == item.Id
          })
          .orderBy(function(value) {
            return value.OrderBy
          })
          .toArray()
        if (subMenu.length > 0) {
          createSubMenu(mainData, subMenu)
        }
      })
      menuHTML += '</li></ul>'
    }
  })
```

Now I am trying to loop li and want to add active class on particular class but menu generated and function call is earlier so it not working. How can I do that.

Run this function after menu creation

```
 $.menuActive = function (menuItem) {
      $('#respMenu li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == menuItem) {
          $(this).addClass('active')
          return false
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: this is really unclear, which function u want to after createMenu, u already called getRequest from Ph

Comment: edited mu code @SuryapratapSingh

Comment: why can't u call this method simply after $('#respMenu').html(menuHTML)?

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh I want to call in different page where I will tell which <li> should be active

Comment: understood, u can fire custom jquery events or use @Pierre Burton answer

Comment: I tired jQuery trigger but not working :(

Comment: That should work pretty straightforward, just make sure $( "#respMenu" ) element is there before trigger or on and u listen first and then trigger, what i mean in event listener should already be there before trigger :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // Do something here

  });
});

mutationObserver.observe(myRefElement, {attributes: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can use custom events
//Do this after  $('#respMenu').html(menuHTML)
$( "#respMenu" ).trigger( "list_ready" );

//In another file
$( "#respMenu" ).on( "list_ready", function () {
//Do ur stuff here
});
```